# Upgraded to pip9.0.3 - *STILL* getting tlsv1 error & can't install packages/libs : Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip

I recently updated pip (as prompted) to 9.0.3 and immediately have fallen foul of the tlsv1 error, eg

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version
>   (_ssl.c:646)'),)': /simple/pywakeonlan/   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywakeonlan/: There was a problem
>   confirming the ssl certificate:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /simple/pywakeonlan/ (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version (_ssl.c:646)'),)) - skipping   Could not find a
>   version that satisfies the requirement pywakeonlan (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pywakeonlan

I've checked out as many of the obviously related questions on SO as I can, but none of them hold a direct answer that I can see.

Running pip with `--trusted-host` makes no difference.

os is Puppy Linux Precise (= Ubuntu 12.04 basically)

I've upgraded my OpenSsl to 1.0.2f, but to no avail.

> Python 3.5.0 (default, Aug 28 2017, 17:57:13)  [GCC 4.6.3] on linux 
>   import ssl
>   print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION) OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012

Clearly there's a mismatch of os OpenSSL version and what Python is picking up.

Short of upgrading to a later os version (this fixes it, I've tested it -
but brings other unrelated  difficulties for me), the only glimmer I have is that I might need to recompile Python now that I have upgraded OpenSSL?

Is this correct?

If so, do I only need the recompiled interpreter plus some selected libs such as ssl perhaps? Or do I need to install the entire suite again?

Comment: You should update your whole distribution. Ubuntu 12.04 is EOL for a year now.

Comment: yep. as stated in my question, that is a problem in itself.

Comment: Old versions of Ubuntu are known to cause these kind of SSL troubles.